# Does Ace indicate which command is running?

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor in a container and commands need to be passed to the container.

With events you can see what event is occurring because you are passed an event object that contains an `event.type` property. Is there a way to know what command is currently occurring? It looks like the `editor` is passed to the `exec` function:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "mycommand",
    bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-M", mac: "Command-Option-M"},
    exec: function(editor) {
        // how to check what command is occurring here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check the command name from command itself use `this.name`.
Otherwise you can use `editor.curOp.command` https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/editor.js#L149.
You can also use `editor.prevOp` to get previous the operation.